# VPS gone after reboot. SSH unavailable / VNC working

Tags: server, ssh, vnc

After a VPS restart enforced by webmin due to an update I (carelessly) did not pay close attention to I have no access to my VPS anymore via SSH. All attempts end in "Connection timed out".

However I still got access to the VPS via VNC. After the log-on I'm stranded in the terminal with half of my keyboard's keys missing (unfortunately backslash and pipe are gone so half of the commands in terminal are not working). As far as I can see with ls the folders are not accessible (though DF shows that my data is still existing somehow). sshd is also up and running according to systemctl, as well as apache, webmin.... still it is all unaccessible.

I am a beginner+ .....still I've never managed to bring myself in a similar situation so at the moment I do not know where to start and how to (hopefully) recover at least bits of the data stored on the VPS.

Is there any approach I should tackle in the firstplace via VNC to limit the damage? Whaterver logs or dumps can shed some light I will be glad to offer.

Any recommendations or guides to proceed are welcome. I'm working without sense and direction at the moment for I don't even have an idea of tackling the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are running ubuntu here(because I had the same problem).
Try to ping 8.8.8.8 from within the VNC to check whether VPS is connected to the network. If not =>
Check /etc/netplan for a backup config file, you should find there the details to config netplan.
After you apply the config, reboot and vps should be online.
If not, create a ticket with your vps prvider, they need to restart the network manager or restore some sort of backup for your network settings.

Comment: You sir are a lifesaver :-). Your solution helped me getting my VPS back online. Do you know the reason why this does happen? Did i miss something when rebooting the VPS? Or is that just a case of bad luck and can happen on Ubuntu server?

Comment: For anyone as unlucky as me, here is what I did in the end: 1 )/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml_backup 2 )cp /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml_backup /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml 3) netplan apply